# C# Attributes from External Class Library

Tags: c#, attributes

I have this very basic class library that has inherited from System.Attribute. I also signed it as an assembly so the dll can be used in another program.

```
namespace BearData
{
  public class BearData : Attribute
  {
    private string[] array1;
    private string bear = "Bear";
    private int weight;

    public BearData(string bear)
    {
        this.bear = bear;
    }
    public string Bear
    {
        get
        {
            return bear;
        }

        set
        {
            bear = value;
        }
    }

    public int Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return weight;
        }

        set
        {
            weight = value;
        }
    }

    public string[] BearTypes()
    {
        array1 = new string[8];
        array1[0] = "Brown/Grizzly";
        array1[1] = "Polar";
        array1[2] = "Asian Black";
        array1[3] = "American Black";
        array1[4] = "Sun";
        array1[5] = "Sloth";
        array1[6] = "Spectacled";
        array1[7] = "Giant Panda";

        return array1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is used in a basic console application. However due to my professor's cryptic, vague, and enigmatic nature, i'm at a stand still on getting this to work.I get an error from this line:

```
bearAttribute = (BearData.BearData)attrs[0];
```

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in Assigntment5_Console.exe" is the exact error.

I guess my specific question what is causing that error?

But also more generally, Is this a good/proper way to use attributes when theyre from an outside library? It seems strange to me that there's random arrays thrown in here and that i'm casting an array to the attribute class?

**By the way. This is how my professor wrote the code for an attribute class isolated in a single Visual Studio instance. He also had an example of class library dll exporting and I was left to my own device to figure out how to combine the 2.**

```
using BearData;
namespace Assigntment5_Console
{
   class Program
  {

    [BearData.BearData("Bear", Weight = 1000)]

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemberInfo attributeInfo;
        attributeInfo = typeof(BearData.BearData);
        object[] attrs = attributeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        //for (int i = 0; i < attrs.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(attrs[i]);
        //}
        BearData.BearData bearAttribute;
        bearAttribute = (BearData.BearData)attrs[0];


        Console.WriteLine("Animal: " + bearAttribute.Bear + "\nAverage Weight: " + bearAttribute.Weight);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the BearData attribute on the Program.Main() method, so you should be looking for the attribute there

The following code should fix your problem

```
namespace Assigntment5_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        [BearData.BearData("Bear", Weight = 1000)]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
            object[] attrs = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BearData.BearData), true);   

            BearData.BearData bearAttribute;
            bearAttribute = (BearData.BearData)attrs[0];   

            Console.WriteLine("Animal: " + bearAttribute.Bear + "\nAverage Weight: " + bearAttribute.Weight);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did definitely get it to work first try. Thanks a lot!